# How to integrate an own Vim color scheme into Neovim?

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I'm on macOS Ventura with iTerm2.

I've made a color scheme for Vim in `~/.vim/colors/myowncolorscheme.vim`.
Is it possible to use it in Neovim? If yes, how do I do that?

In my `~.vimrc` I integrate it this way:

```
" Set the color scheme of Vim:
colorscheme myowncolorscheme
set termguicolors
```

In Vim, my own color scheme works properly.

Regards,
Manny

Comment: This should be entirely possibly by putting the colorscheme in NeoVim's runtimepath (probably `~/.config/nvim/colors/xy.vim` or something; use `stdpath` or similar to find the appropriate place)

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble, but that didn’t worked for me :/

Comment: You need to call the colorscheme command correctly. Try the `:help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1 - .vimrc as source

If in Vim everything works properly and if you have Neovim already installed, create the file `init.vim` in Neovim directory with the command:

```
touch ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Now open this file with any editor you like (I use Neovim for this example):

```
nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

...and put following content into it:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath = &runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
```

Safe and close `init.vim` with `shift + ZZ` or `:wq`.
If you now open a file with Neovim, the color scheme that is activated in Vim is activated in Neovim too.

Maybe this way can lead into trouble if you have already an `init.lua` file in `~/.config/nvim/` directory.
If so, just rename `init.lua` to `foobarinit.lua` to see if your `init.vim` works. Keep in mind, that everything of `*.vim` is more important than `*.lua`. So if you have, your Neovim plugins get disabled.

### Solution 2 - init.lua as source

Like @Pixelbog said (tanks by the way), create a color directory in `~/.config/nvim/` directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim/colors
```

Copy your Vim color scheme into that directory:

```
cp ~/.vim/colors/myowncolorscheme.vim ~/.config/nvim/colors/myowncolorscheme.vim
```

Now open your `init.lua` in `~/config/nvim/` with any editor you like (I use Neovim for this example):

```
nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.lua
```

...and put following content into it:

```
vim.opt.termguicolors = true
vim.cmd("colorscheme myowncolorscheme")
```

Safe and close `init.vim` with `shift + ZZ` or `:wq`.
If you now open a file with Neovim, the color scheme is activated in Neovim.
The two `vim.*` lines of `init.lua` you can write in any `*.lua` file in `~/.config/nvim/lua/*` directory, but then you have to require that file in `init.lua`:

```
require("settings.core.options")
```

For this example the absolute path is `~/.config/nvim/lua/settings/core/options.lua`.

Comment: I think the `vim.cmd` to call `:colorscheme` is the most important part of this answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Yes. simply **create** the this directory:

`mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim/colors`

Then **move**/**copy** your colorsheme file into the directory:

`mv ~/.vim/colors/xy.vim ~/.config/nvim/colors/xy.vim`

---

In case you have changed the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable, put it in accordingly...